# mod_rewrite /dir/index.html to /dir/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to automatic change with htaccess this:

```
/dir1/index.html  -> /dir1/ (with 301 redirect)
/dir1/subdir1/index.html -> /dir1/subdir1/ (with 301 redirect)
...
/another_dir/index.html  -> /another_dir/ (with 301 redirect)
/another_dir/another_subdir1/index.html -> /another_dir/another_subdir1/ (with 301 redirect)
```

etc.

Files index.html is physically exist on directories

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This code will redirect everything that ends with `index.html` (where the file actually exists).

Comment: this construction not supported subflolders and  
/another_dir/another_subdir1/index.html will change to/another_subdir1/

Comment: It should work, as the `.*` capture group includes forward slashes. Have you tried it? And where is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: my htaccess 

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ $1/ [R=301,L]

Comment: What does it do? And **where** is the file located on your server? Is it in the public root?

Comment: my htaccess 

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

and real structure is: 
http://test2.prelux.ru/.htaccess
http://test2.prelux.ru/index.html
http://test2.prelux.ru/folder1/index.html
http://test2.prelux.ru/folder2/index.html
http://test2.prelux.ru/folder1/subfolder1/index.html

Comment: I add RewriteBase   / 

Thanks)